# How can I match a tab to the end of the line with a Perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file with the below contents:

```
After learning everything you've learned so far, 
you may think you've bingo: got a pretty good foundation in 
programming Perl, since you'd already be a good way 
through most of the concepts many other languages entail. 
endbingo: But if you put down 
this book today and did nothing else
bingo: with Perl beyond what I've already taught you, 
you'd miss 
endbingo: thats ok.
```

I need a Perl regular expression to match the lines "bingo: got a pretty good foundation in" and "bingo: with Perl beyond what I've already taught you"..

In the sense, the word "bingo:followed by a tab, followed by any random set of characters till the end of line".

Comment: does the "bingo" have to be anchored to the start of a line or can it be mid-line, like the 2nd line in your example?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have not posted any code of your own, I will presume you are not even sure how to begin to construct a Perl regular expression.  Here are some resources to get you started.

From the official Perl documentation website:

- [perlintro](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Regular-expressions)
- [perlrequick](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html)
- [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html)

I realize that this does not directly answer your question (as others have already done), but perhaps it will help you to converge more quickly on a solution to a future problem.

Answer (score 0):

In multiline mode try:

```
 \Wbingo:\s.*$
```

`\W` means any non alphanumeric char

`\s` means white char (space, tab, new line)

`.*` means zero or more random characters

`$` means end of line

Answer (score 0):

if by match, you just want to show the lines with "bingo:" and tab onwards, then

```
perl -ne 'print if /bingo:\s+.+$/' file
```

if you want to match the word "bingo:" but not "endbingo:", then

```
$ perl -ne 'print if /\bbingo:\s+.+$/' file
you may think you've bingo: got a pretty good foundation in
bingo: with Perl beyond what I've already taught you,
```

Answer (score 0):

So it should not match endbingo ? Try this:

```
/(?<!end)bingo:\s+.*$/
```

the (?<! is a negative lookbehind and is the proper way to exclude the endbingo without excluding cases where the "bingo:" immediately follows some non-blank text.

Otherwise, if there is always whitespace behind the bingo, just do /\sbingo:\s+(.*)$/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking a tab and not all white space use the following:

```
/bingo:\t.*$/
```

If the line must start with "bingo:" you should use this:

```
/^bingo:\t.*$/
```